# What is the best specific for fast relay?

Tags: relays, configuration, middle

I'm trying to setup Tor relay, just a middle, not an Exit.

I'm looking for the best configuration for the 100 mb / s. My current `torrc` is:

```
V3AuthoritativeDirectory 1
V3AuthVotingInterval 30 minutes

DisableAllSwap 1
AvoidDiskWrites 1

NumCPUs 4
DownloadExtraInfo 1
FetchUselessDescriptors 1

ORPort 9001
ORListenAddress 0.0.0.0:9001
DirPort 9030 # what port to advertise for directory connections
DirListenAddress 0.0.0.0:9030

RelayBandwidthRate  50 MB  # Throttle traffic to 100KB/s (800Kbps)
RelayBandwidthBurst 100 MB # But allow bursts up to 200KB/s (1600Kbps)
MaxAdvertisedBandwidth 100MB

ExitPolicy reject *:*
```

What is the best configuration options to prevent highload on the my workstation, and achieve as much cool for the Tor Network as possible?

I'm talking about:

- Setup big bandwidths between Exits and Entries, and skip low. To prevent DDOS on the side of OS's IP addr table.
- Setup Tor daemon in such way to prevent high load on the Disk sub-system, like Avoid Disk Writes, etc.
- Keep highest and more relevancy Tor relays ( much more oldest ) in work with me.

Any ways to keep full 50 mb/s, the half of my real speed in job.

Currently, for the whole of week, my `arm`, tor console face give only:

```
flags: Fast, Running, V2Dir, Valid             exit policy: reject *:*

page 1 / 5 - m: menu, p: pause, h: page help, q: quit
Download (13.4 Kb/sec   - avg: 138.8 Kb/sec, total: 520.7 MB):     Upload (145.3 Kb/sec  - avg: 190.2 Kb/sec, total: 710.7 MB)
```

I don't know how, I don't know why, it doesn't take my bandwidth. Doesn't take more than 1mb/s. What is it? My OS is the last Ubuntu.

Comment: Note that 100MB means 100 mega**bytes**. (Do you have gigabit down **and up**?) Your `MaxAdvertizedBandwidth` should not be higher than your `RelayBandwidthRate`.

Answer (score 2):

As you are not setting up a directory authority, `V3AuthoritativeDirectory` `V3AuthVotingInterval` should not be set.

Tor will not put load on your disk. It will use bandwidth, CPU and memory. Disk usage is marginal in any cases.

For the rest, I suggest looking at the documentation on [how to setup a high speed relay](https://www.torservers.net/wiki/setup/server) on Torservers.net wiki.